# PaginationSample Javafx cannot assign a value to final variable pagination

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to reproduce a Pagination Sample from oracle samples, but when I imported the project something strange happened that I can not build and run the project:

The complete code is:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class PaginationSample extends Application {

    private final Pagination pagination;
    private Image[] images = new Image[7];

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        VBox outerBox = new VBox();
        outerBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //Images for our pages
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image(PaginationSample.class.getResource("animal" + (i + 1) + ".jpg").toExternalForm(), false);
        }

        pagination = PaginationBuilder.create().pageCount(7).pageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
            @Override public Node call(Integer pageIndex) {
                return createAnimalPage(pageIndex);
            }
        }).build();
        //Style can be numeric page indicators or bullet indicators
        Button styleButton = ButtonBuilder.create().text("Toggle pagination style").onAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent me) {
                if (!pagination.getStyleClass().contains(Pagination.STYLE_CLASS_BULLET)) {
                    pagination.getStyleClass().add(Pagination.STYLE_CLASS_BULLET);
                } else {
                    pagination.getStyleClass().remove(Pagination.STYLE_CLASS_BULLET);
                }
            }
        }).build();

        outerBox.getChildren().addAll(pagination, styleButton);
        root.getChildren().add(outerBox);
    }
    //Creates the page content
    private VBox createAnimalPage(int pageIndex) {
        VBox box = new VBox();
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(images[pageIndex]);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Label desc = new Label("PAGE " + (pageIndex + 1));
        box.getChildren().addAll(iv, desc);
        return box;
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

But netbeans show me the error "cannot assign a value to final variable pagination" for the following line:

```
pagination = PaginationBuilder.create().pageCount(7).pageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
```

Someone can explain me what is going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A final field can be initialized only once. So the best place to initialize it is when its declared

```
private final Pagination pagination = new Pagination(...);
```

or it can be done in the constructor, since the constructor is assured to be called once per instance

```
private final Pagination pagination;

public PaginationSample() {
    pagination = new Pagination(...);
}
```

`final` field **cannot be** initialized in a **method** because a method can be called multiple times once an instance of that class gets created

Comment: Thanks, as it is a sample from Oracle I almost didn't check the code, thanks and sorry for the stupid question.